# How to pass variable from inside click function to set variable outside to zero

Tags: javascript

I have a variable called progress as in below

When clicked an image as in below, I want the progress to set to 0; I am trying below

```
var progress = 10;
var progress2 = $(".close2 img").click(function() { 
 // if user clicks the reset button (Start Over) then
 var progress = 0;
 //console.log(progress);
 return progress;
});
```

But it fails.. The progress is set to zero within scope. But outside I am having trouble passing it...can someone help me out to figure out the mistake I am making?

Comment: You can't return from a click function, progress2 is a jQuery object containing the image element ?

Comment: Excellent point @adeneo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
    $(".close2 img").click(function() { 
        progress = 0;
        //console.log(progress);
        return progress;
    });
```

When you use var, you are creating a variable (whith the same name) inside the function.

PD: as @adeneo said, it's useless to try to capture the output of a jQuery listener. Your declaration of progress2 will always be an array of DOM elements.

Take, for instance this function

```
var true_body=jQuery('body').click(function() { return true; });
```

It could seem as if true_body would always receive `true` as its value. Truth is, true_body is

`[<body>....all body contents here...</body>]`

Comment: It's a bit misleading to say that the return value is an array of DOM elements. Really, it's a jQuery object, which will always wrap one or more DOM elements for any useful application of 'click'. But the object returned is not an array of DOM elements...

Comment: You're right, it's not a real array because it inherits jQuery's methods, but it behaves like an array in that you can actually access the raw DOM element with jQuery(selector)[0].

Answer (score 2):

You are setting local variable `progress` to 0, while outer `progress` is intact. Remove `var` from `var progress = 0;` to not declare new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is declaring a new progress variable local to the scope of your click handler. You can access the progress variable from the enclosing scope like this:

```
  var progress = 10;

  $(".close2 img").click(function() {
       progress = 0;
  });
```